# Excel sheet Formula Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have excel sheet where I need to fetch the column name header name if the column value is set to 1. And that to a new column in each row. Is that possible to do via a formula or is a  Macro required?

Below image shows 4 column and the 5th column has the details of the groups each end user is part of(where ever group A,B or C is 1)

[image]

-----UPDATE
After doing suggested solutions, both is giving error in the below evaluation. Attaching the screenshot.

[image]

I tried in Excel 2019 as well

Comment: Show us your spreadsheet with a good example and a better explanation than this one.

Comment: Sure..Have attached a screenshot now..

Comment: I rejected your edit as it wasn't done on your question directly. I have edited the question and included the part from the (your) edit.

Comment: oh okok..sorry about that..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula in E2:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF(B2:D2=1,$B$1:$D$1,""))
```

Drag down to fill the other cells. Enable Wrap Text for column E's cells .

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding, I tried the above but it is giving me error when I am using B2:D2 . but when i use B2=1, it works . It doesn't seem to work when it has to check multiple columns.

Comment: thank you..I upgraded to O365 and This worked!!

Answer (score 0):

You have the `microsoft-excel-2016` tag set. `TEXTJOIN` will not work in Excel 2016 as it was not added until the 2019 version.

Try `CONCAT` instead. It's a bit less slick in this situation because adding a delimiter (the `CHAR(10)` that puts each header name on its own line) also adds one to the end giving you an extra, blank, line.

```
=LEFT( CONCAT(IF(B4:D4=1,$B$1:$D$1,"") & CHAR(10)),
```

LEN( CONCAT(IF(B4:D4=1,$B$1:$D$1,"") & CHAR(10))  ) - 1)

which adds probably the easiest way to remove that last delimiter, but it doubles the length of the formula.

(The approach is the same, really, just a less suitable function due to Excel improving over the years. It just goes to show how nice `TEXTJOIN` is, that the vast improvement on `CONCATENATE`, the `CONCAT` function, was still replaced by the even better `TEXTJOIN` in the next version.)

Comment: Hello @jeorje. I tried the above as well but when evaluating =1 part, it gives error. Attached is the screenshot in the post.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out about the compatibility issue. It worked now